# How to fix (unreachable code ts.7027) react native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I am new to React Native and still learning. Everything was working well but suddenly I got and error in the emulator and also in code editor and spent two days trying to find a solution but found nothing

I am getting two errors 
1) In code editor (unreachable code ts.7027
2) In emulator (the development server returned response error code : 500)

I tried a lot to change and revise the code may be some syntax error or even spelling but I couldn't
This is for new react-native project
This of creating Login page form

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import {Header, Button, Spinner} from './Components/Common';
import LoginForm from './Components/LoginForm';



class App extends Component {
  state = { loggedIn: null };

  componentWillMount () {
    firebase.initializeApp(
      {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyAX09VgJkSzx3d5z8UcyznmhTUNLUgYzMw",
    authDomain: "hatimauth.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://hatimauth.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "hatimauth",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "62394723382",
    appId: "1:62394723382:web:bd5e4bb7a365a05b"
  });

  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
      this.setState({loggedIn: true});
    }else {
      this.setState({loggedIn: false });
    }
  });


renderContent () {
 switch (this.state.loggedIn) {
   case true:
     return (
     <Button onPress{()=> firebase.auth().signOut()}> Log Out
      </Button>
     );
   case false:
     return <LoginForm/>;
   default:
    return <Spinner size='large'/>;
    }
}

render () {
  return (
    <View>
      <Header headerText='Authentication'/>
      {this.renderContent}
    </View>
  )
};

export default App;
```

Expected to run normally especially that it's run normally through the course video 
The course is udemy react-native and redux full course

Comment: You are missing closing brackets for `componentWillMount` as well as for your `class`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the closing bracket on the componentWillMount. I would recommend downloading a linter, something like prettier for your IDE.

```
componentWillMount () {
    firebase.initializeApp(
      {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyAX09VgJkSzx3d5z8UcyznmhTUNLUgYzMw",
    authDomain: "hatimauth.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://hatimauth.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "hatimauth",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "62394723382",
    appId: "1:62394723382:web:bd5e4bb7a365a05b"
  });

  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
      this.setState({loggedIn: true});
    }else {
      this.setState({loggedIn: false });
    }
  });
}
```

Additionally, I would recommend learning how to work with .env files and put them in a git ignore so that you aren't sharing your API key with the world (sharing a good package to look through):

https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config

Comment: Additionally, one other thing to note is that ```ComponentWillMount``` is now deprecated.  I would look into using ```ComponentDidUpdate```